# Acentos com QString no Qt 5.9 resulta em caracteres bizarros

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Oi, boa tarde, to com uma duvida que eu nao consigo arrumar de jeito nenhum
o código é o seguinte....

> ```
>        QTextStream stream( &file );
>              stream.setCodec("ISO 8859-1");
>              stream << "<p align=center><font size=4><font face=times><b>PROCURAÇÃO AD JUDICIA E ET EXTRA</b></font></font></center>" << ent << ent << ent << "<font size=3,25><font face=times><p align=justify> Por este instrumento particular, ", << "<b>" << noM << "</b>" << " brasileiro(a), " << ciV << ", " << emP<< ", portador(a) da Cédula de Identidade número RG n. " << rG /*"<<, nascido em: "<<*/ << ", inscrito(a) no CPF sob n. " << cpF << ", PIS " << piS << ", CTPS / N. / Série " << ctpS << ", e-mail: <u>" << emA << "</u>, residente e domiciliado(a) na " << enD << ", " << ceP<< " - " << ciD << "/" << esT<< ", nomeia e constitui como seus procuradores e advogados, <b>Antônio Sérgio Meorin - OAB/SP n. 328.518 e Júlio César Lopes de Araújo - OAB/SP n. 379.678</b>, ambos, com escritório profissional situado na Rua Paraíba, 583, Centro, São Joaquim da Barra/SP, aos quais confere os poderes da presente procuração para o foro em geral, inclusive o <i>et extra</i>, para, independente da ordem de nomeação, agir em nome do(a) outorgante, em quaisquer Juízos, instâncias, Tribunais, Repartições Públicas, com amplos e ilimitados poderes, podendo propor as ações competentes e defendê-o(a) nas contrárias, seguinda umas e outras até final decisão, usando os recursos, desistindo ou dispensando-os, podendo praticar todos os atos que se tornarem necessários, ao útil, bom e fiel desempenho deste mandato, inclusive substavelecer, com ou sem reservas de poderes, receber intimação, confessar, reconhecer a procedência do pedido, transigir, desistir, renunciar, receber e dar recibo, dar quitação, acordar e firmar compromisso." << ent << ent << "Declaro, para os fins de concessão dos benefícios da Justiça Gratuita que, em conformidade com o disposto na CF de 88, artigo 5º, LXXIV e Leis n.º1060/50 e 7.115/83, <u>sob as penas da lei</u>, art. 299 do CP, que sou pessoa <b>pobre</b>, na <u>acepção legal exata do termo</u>, cuja situação financeira não permite pagar as custas do processo, sem prejuízo do sustento próprio ou da família." << ent << ent << "Por ser verdade, e para que surta seus legais e jurídicos efeitos, assina a presente, nesta data, sob as penas da lei." << ent << ent << "<p align=left>São Joaquim da Barra/SP, " << proC << "." << ent << ent << ent << ent << "<center><b>______________________________________</b></center>" << ent << "<center>OUTORGANTE</center></b></font></font>" ;
> ```

até ai tudo bem, apesar da bagunça (estou começando e nem sei como pular linhas sem quebrar o código) o código funciona, o digitado no stream, após o setCodec fica normal, entretanto, o set codec não transforma as variaveis que eu criei em QString, bugam nos acentos, por exemplo, o nome:

> Por este instrumento particular, OT?IO JEFERS? brasileiro(a), solteiro(a), 561, portador(a) da **Cédula**

O nome deveria sair "OTÁVIO JEFERSÃO", porém, é substituido por ?, enquanto o resto sai normalmente, como  a "Cédula" que foi grifada.... o que está acontecendo, e como posso arrumar? Se eu seto o codec pra UTF-8, as variaveis ficam normais e o resto do texto fica todo zuado....
qual a solução? To nisso há dias...

segue a lista das variaveis criadas:

> ```
> QString noM = ui->lineNome->text().toUpper();
> QString ceP = ui->lineCep->text();
> QString ciD = ui->lineCid->text();
> QString cpF = ui->lineCpf->text();
> QString ctpS = ui->lineCtps->text();
> QString rG = ui->lineRg->text();
> QString enD = ui->lineEnd->text();
> QString esT = ui->boxEst->currentText();
> QDate daT = ui->dateDat->date();
> QString nuM = ui->lineNum->text();
> QString ciV = ui->boxCiv->currentText();
> QString emP = ui->lineEmp->text().toLower();
> QString comP = (nuM) + (" - ") + (noM);
> QString piS = ui->linePis->text();
> QString emA = ui->lineEma->text();
> QString proC = ui->lineProc->text();
> ```

Obrigado, desde já, aceito sugestoes de materiais para aprendizado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem 2 motivos pelo qual isto ocorre:

1. é porque `QString` internamente trabalha com `latin1`, o outro motivo é que
2. Todos arquivos gerados pelo QtCreator são codificados em UTF-8, ou seja até mesmo os `.cpp` e `.h`

Então ao tentar mesclar os dados do `.cpp` que no caso são estes:

```
stream << "<p align=center><font size=4><font face=times><b>PROCURAÇÃO...
```

E quando seta o valor de `ui->lineNome->text()` para um `QString` você estará trabalhando com diferentes codificações, se o seu "html" fosse setado em uma `QString` antes de passar no `QTextStream`.

Então o `.cpp` aonde você escreveu o seu "HTML" dentro do stream esta em UTF-8 e `ui->lineNome->text()` deve estar com latin1. Quando você tenta decodificar com:

```
 stream.setCodec("ISO-8859-1");
```

Ou algo parecido ele vai afetar todo o `stream`, e como tem unicode misturado com latin1 ele tentará decodificar algo que já esta decodificado, gerando os sinais de interrogação como `OT?IO JEFERS?`

Eu efetuei um teste, abri o meu `.cpp`, criei pelo QtCreator mesmo um projeto, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(ui->btnSave, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(save()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::save()
{
    QString filename = "data.txt";
    QFile file(filename);

    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << "Titulo:" << "Olá mundo!" << endl;
        stream << "Nome:" << ui->nomeDoCliente->text() << endl;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Abri o `widget.cpp` pelo sublimetext e ele mostrava utf8, como na imagem:

[image: cpp utf8]

Compilei e executei o programa, então no campo `nomeDoCliente` digitei `Á É Í Ó Ú` e cliquei no botão salvar que executou `Widget::save`, o conteúdo gerado foi este:

```
Titulo:OlÃ¡ mundo!
Nome:Á É Í Ó Ú
```

E no sublimetext mostra ele sendo como windows-1252, ou seja o `OlÃ¡` são caracteres do utf-8 misturados com o latin1

Depois salvei o `widget.cpp` como iso-8859-1 (compatível com latin1) pelo sublimetext, ele ficou assim:

[image: cpp iso-8850-1]

Então recompilei o projeto inteiro, executei o programa e clique em salvar, o `data.txt` agora possui este conteúdo:

```
Titulo:Olá mundo!
Nome:Á É Í Ó Ú
```

Veja, não foi necessário `setCodec` nem nada, o arquivo `data.txt` ficou com os acentos perfeitos e pelo sublimetext ele acusa como windows-1252 (compativel com latin1).

---

### Como resolver

No entanto ficar abrindo um por um dos seus `.cpp` e salvando como windows-1252 ou iso-8859-1 não é tarefa fácil, ainda mais se estiver usando o QtCreator, pra simplificar basta deixar todos valores em `QString` sempre pois assim ele irá usar a codificação padrão sempre, veja um exemplo que funcionou:

```
void Widget::save()
{
    QString textopadrao = "Olá mundo!";
    QString nome = ui->nomeDoCliente->text();

    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << "Titulo:" << textopadrao << endl;
        stream << "Nome:" << nome << endl;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Após salvar tanto o valor vindo do `nomeDoCliente` quanto o que estava no `textopadrao` usaram a mesma codificação.

Então faça isto no seu código (adicione quebras de linhas porque fica mais fácil):

```
QString conteudoHtml = ""
    "<p align=center><font size=4><font face=times><b>"
    "PROCURAÇÃO AD JUDICIA E ET EXTRA</b></font></font></center>"
    "" + ent + ent + ent + "<font size=3,25><font face=times>"
    "<p align=justify> Por este instrumento particular, " + "<b>"
    "" + noM + "</b>" + " brasileiro(a), " + ciV + ", " + emP + ""
    ", portador(a) da Cédula de Identidade número RG n. rG "
    "nascido em: " + ", inscrito(a) no CPF sob n. " + cpF + ", PIS "
    "" + piS + ", CTPS / N. / Série " + ctpS + ", e-mail: <u>" + emA + ""
    "</u>, residente e domiciliado(a) na " + enD + ", " + ceP + " - "
    "" + ciD + "/" + esT + ", nomeia e constitui como seus procuradores e advogados,"
    " <b>Antônio Sérgio Meorin - OAB/SP n. 328.518 e Júlio César Lopes de Araújo -"
    " OAB/SP n. 379.678</b>, ambos, com escritório profissional situado na Rua"
    " Paraíba, 583, Centro, São Joaquim da Barra/SP, aos quais confere os poderes"
    " da presente procuração para o foro em geral, inclusive o <i>et extra</i>,"
    " para, independente da ordem de nomeação, agir em nome do(a) outorgante, em"
    " quaisquer Juízos, instâncias, Tribunais, Repartições Públicas, com amplos e"
    " ilimitados poderes, podendo propor as ações competentes e defendê-o(a) nas"
    " contrárias, seguinda umas e outras até final decisão, usando os recursos,"
    " desistindo ou dispensando-os, podendo praticar todos os atos que se tornarem"
    " necessários, ao útil, bom e fiel desempenho deste mandato, inclusive"
    " substavelecer, com ou sem reservas de poderes, receber intimação, confessar,"
    " reconhecer a procedência do pedido, transigir, desistir, renunciar, receber e"
    " dar recibo, dar quitação, acordar e firmar compromisso." + ent + ent + ""
    " Declaro, para os fins de concessão dos benefícios da Justiça Gratuita que, em"
    " conformidade com o disposto na CF de 88, artigo 5º, LXXIV e Leis n.º1060/50 e"
    " 7.115/83, <u>sob as penas da lei</u>, art. 299 do CP, que sou pessoa <b>pobre</b>,"
    " na <u>acepção legal exata do termo</u>, cuja situação financeira não permite"
    " pagar as custas do processo, sem prejuízo do sustento próprio ou da família."
    "" + ent + ent + "Por ser verdade, e para que surta seus legais e jurídicos efeitos,"
    " assina a presente, nesta data, sob as penas da lei." + ent + ent + ""
    "<p align=left>São Joaquim da Barra/SP, " + proC + "." + ent + ent + ent + ""
    "" + ent + "<center><b>______________________________________</b></center>" + ent + ""
    "<center>OUTORGANTE</center></b></font></font>";

if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << conteudoHtml << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Se deseja salvar como UTF-8 basta fazer isto:

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
    stream << conteudoHtml << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Efetuei o teste e funcionou perfeitamente, note que para testes eu setei todas variáveis com o valor do campo "Nome" que no caso foi este `"isso é um teste blá á ã ô"`, e funcionou perfeitamente gerando este resultado no `data.txt`:

> ```
> <p align=center><font size=4><font face=times><b>PROCURAÇÃO AD JUDICIA E ET EXTRA</b></font></font></center>
>
>
> <font size=3,25><font face=times><p align=justify> Por este instrumento particular, <b>"isso é um teste blá á ã ô"</b> brasileiro(a), "isso é um teste blá á ã ô", "isso é um teste blá á ã ô", portador(a) da Cédula de Identidade número RG n. rG nascido em: , inscrito(a) no CPF sob n. "isso é um teste blá á ã ô", PIS "isso é um teste blá á ã ô", CTPS / N. / Série "isso é um teste blá á ã ô", e-mail: <u>"isso é um teste blá á ã ô"</u>, residente e domiciliado(a) na "isso é um teste blá á ã ô", "isso é um teste blá á ã ô" - "isso é um teste blá á ã ô"/"isso é um teste blá á ã ô", nomeia e constitui como seus procuradores e advogados, <b>Antônio Sérgio Meorin - OAB/SP n. 328.518 e Júlio César Lopes de Araújo - OAB/SP n. 379.678</b>, ambos, com escritório profissional situado na Rua Paraíba, 583, Centro, São Joaquim da Barra/SP, aos quais confere os poderes da presente procuração para o foro em geral, inclusive o <i>et extra</i>, para, independente da ordem de nomeação, agir em nome do(a) outorgante, em quaisquer Juízos, instâncias, Tribunais, Repartições Públicas, com amplos e ilimitados poderes, podendo propor as ações competentes e defendê-o(a) nas contrárias, seguinda umas e outras até final decisão, usando os recursos, desistindo ou dispensando-os, podendo praticar todos os atos que se tornarem necessários, ao útil, bom e fiel desempenho deste mandato, inclusive substavelecer, com ou sem reservas de poderes, receber intimação, confessar, reconhecer a procedência do pedido, transigir, desistir, renunciar, receber e dar recibo, dar quitação, acordar e firmar compromisso.
>
>  Declaro, para os fins de concessão dos benefícios da Justiça Gratuita que, em conformidade com o disposto na CF de 88, artigo 5º, LXXIV e Leis n.º1060/50 e 7.115/83, <u>sob as penas da lei</u>, art. 299 do CP, que sou pessoa <b>pobre</b>, na <u>acepção legal exata do termo</u>, cuja situação financeira não permite pagar as custas do processo, sem prejuízo do sustento próprio ou da família.
>
> Por ser verdade, e para que surta seus legais e jurídicos efeitos, assina a presente, nesta data, sob as penas da lei.
>
> <p align=left>São Joaquim da Barra/SP, "isso é um teste blá á ã ô".
>
>
>
> <center><b>______________________________________</b></center>
> <center>OUTORGANTE</center></b></font></font>
> ```

Comment: Cara, não testei ainda, mas faz muito sentido o que você falou! Não acredito que não pensei nisso, isso mostra que tenho muito caminho pela frente mesmo! Achei uma honra ser respondido por vc, vi seu perfil ontem! Fez muito pela comunidade! Se puder me indicar algum material pra iniciar, eu agradeço! Máximo respeito...

Comment: @creepohard obrigado! Então algumas coisas do Qt aprendi no StackOverflow mesmo, outras eu aprendi lendo os exemplos http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html#examples, que apesar de em inglês me ajudaram bastante, eu pessoalmente gosto de aprender testando, depois eu vou pra documentação ler os detalhes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/reference-overview.html, espero que ajude, e se tiver duvidas é só perguntar, além de mim tem mais 4 usuários no site que dominam bem o Qt.